# Running a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, passwords

I downloaded the following PowerShell script from this page. This script is supposed to generate random passwords:

http://blog.simonw.se/powershell-generating-random-password-for-active-directory/

The issue is that when I run that script from PowerShell, I get no output even after I use the parameters as shown in the example. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the script or the function?  That script just defines a function.  If you want to use it try:

```
. pathtoscript
New-SWRandomPassword
```

Comment: I'm running the script. Tried "./New-SWRandomPassword" (without quotes) from the directory it's stored in but no output. Also tried the full path but same result.

Comment: My output from PowershellISE
`PS M:\Scripts> . .\New-SWRandomPassword.ps1
PS M:\Scripts> New-SWRandomPassword
Cg"3RxARo`

Comment: You aren't doing what Jason told you. Open Powershell, type a period, press space, then the path to your script that you downloaded (including file name), and any arguments. This is called Dot Sourcing, and is something you should probably Google and educate yourself about.